# When and why should one subtract the mean before computing autocorrelation function

Tags: autocorrelation

There are two definitions of autocorrelation function. The more popular among statistician is:

$$ R(\tau) = \frac{E[(X_t - \mu)(X_{t+\tau} - \mu)]}{\sigma^2} $$

However the signal processing community ignores subtracting mean and dividing by standard-deviation.

The curve can look very different depending on which definition is used. I was wondering if both of these definitions are equivalent despite the very different shapes of autocorrelation curve one gets. Following is an example:

Following image shows autocorrelation computed without subtracting mean. Normalized to 1. 
[image: This is computed without subtracting mean and dividing by std.]

This image shows autocorrelation computed after subtracting mean and dividing by std.

[image]

Comment: Re "the signal processing community ignores subtracting mean and dividing by standard-deviation." Could you provide a reference or two for this?  I rather suspect that recentering is not done only in cases where the signal is known or assumed to have zero mean already.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html says that "This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal processing texts:" $c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])$

Comment: @whuber this is also a question I have. Whys the Wikipedia Definition without normalisation called autocorrelation if the single distinction between autocorrelation and autocovariance is that the former is normalised and the latter isn't. It should be called autocovariance right? What's more is that there's no mean subtraction, with no explanation, which is only the same as the autocovariance if the mean is 0.

Comment: granted that if it is a WSS the mean subtraction is not required because its always the same, but then the autocovariance definition includes it when the autocorrelation doesn't... don't know why

Comment: Box et al. defines the autocorrelation (at lag $k$) of a stationary time series $z_t$ as $\rho_k = E[(z_t - \mu)(z_{t+k} - \mu)] / \sigma_z^2$, where $\mu = E[z_t]$ is the (constant) mean of the process.  Whereas, Proakis et al. defines the autocorrelation of a stationary, discrete random process as $\gamma_{xx}(m) = E(X_n X_{n-m})$ with the mean of the random process also defined as $m_x = E(X_n)$. So the mean is not subtracted when computing the latter version of the autocorrelation.